# Editing labels for contacts with multiple email addresses

Tags: google-contacts, contacts-group

It looks like the latest version of Google Contacts is not allowing the labels/groups to be edited with the drop down menu anymore - when there are multiple email addresses listed for a single contact. i.e. I want to be able to include selected emails addresses within that contact to a specific label/group - and be able to review and edit later.

Does anyone know of a workaround? I can't seem to go back to the earlier version that allowed the labels to be easily edited.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way how to assign individual labels per each email address of one and same contact - you can't. Labels are meant to group contacts, not email addresses of contacts (at least at this latest version of Google Contacts). The only way how to do so is split email addresses and have it each per contact and then label them individually.

Comment: thanks for your response - no I'm not trying to assign individual labels per each email address.  I just want to be able assign certain emails to a group label.  Very strange that G would inhibit this as nowadays people have at least 2 or more email addresses (i.e. work, home, other...) I just want to be able to select which of those addresses to use in my group label for email communications.

Comment: @PaulMacD I understood and unfortunately, this is not possible atm

Comment: @PaulMacD https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers